# How Would I Take Table And Then Return Only Items That Show Up 3 Times Or More?

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Dog_Name | Dog_Type
Speed    | Mastiff
Cow      | Dalmatian
Mr. Pym  | Siberian Husky
Speed    | Mastiff
```

As you can see, Speed is a bit of a problem dog and has been passed through our system a few times.

From this table, how would I write a query that only returns Speed because he is in the system twice?

I assumed I would need a statement like:

```
HAVING COUNT(Dog_Name) > 1
```

but there can be more then 1 dog with the same name, so I want to make sure it has the same breed as well.

```
HAVING COUNT(Dog_Name) > 1
```

Returned the right answer, but I'm pretty sure it's logically incorrect. Any advice would be marvelous. :)

Comment: You are looking for [`Group By`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) combined with [`Having`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How get the T-SQL code to find duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222581/how-get-the-t-sql-code-to-find-duplicates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use two keys in the `group by`:

```
select Dog_Name, Dog_Type
from t
group by Dog_Name, Dog_Type
having count(*) > 1;
```

That said, I'm sure every breed has multiple examples of Bella and Max.  You probably need better identifying information.